# How can I check the cyclomatic complexity of an Xcode project's source?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cyclomatic-complexity

I need to analyse a large Xcode project for its [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

Has anyone got an easy way of checking the cyclomatic complexity of their code contained within an Xcode project?

Is there a tool that is setup to read xcode projects, perhaps? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found [this python script project](http://code.google.com/p/headerfile-free-cyclomatic-complexity-analyzer/)  to be the most useful.

It works well with XCode projects, because it ignores headers and #imports/includes - this is the main issue with other static analysing tools working with XCode - you have to configure it to find the SDK etc.

Hope this helps someone else who was looking for a CC tool like I was.

cheers :)